# google cloud datastore query performance

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, database-performance

I am working on improving the performance of application which is running with google cloud datastore.
The application itself will run the queries like below as sequence:

```
Select * from table where type = "role" and roleId ="admin"
Select * from table where type = "role" and roleId ="editor"
Select * from table where type = "role" and roleId ="reader"
Select * from table where type = "role" and roleId ="writer"
......
```

The issue is when running 1 it costs >2 seconds,
but the 2-4 are only milliseconds needed.
It seems like the java need to wake up the google cloud datastore(or construct the connection for the 1st time which is time consuming), and others queries are very quick.

My query is why for the first time it costs 100 times time longer than the rest consecutive queries, and how to make sure the queries are quickly enough responsive and no delay for the first query.

Hope any google cloud datastore expert can help, thanks.

Comment: did you find an answer ?

Comment: Do the results change if you change the order of those queries or are the last 3 queries faster than the first regardless of which one is run first?  I have a very likely explanation but must confirm with your results in case you're seeing different fetch times for a different reason.

Comment: @Nicholas, regardless with the order of those queries, it just slower when execute the first query, then other queries are super fast enough for about milliseconds,  so I'm not sure if GAE needs some time to construct the connection with the datastore.

Comment: I have a few theories but not quite enough information to confirm.  First, I do believe you are correct about the time required for App Engine to initially connect to Datastore.  The latency of subsequent Datastore calls is reduced after the connection is established.

Comment: Secondly, Datastore does have its own internal cache to speed up subsequent access though I am not privy to all the inner workings.  I would speculate however that when the first query is executed, the results of `where type = "role"` are cached  before fetching only those with `roleId = "admin"`.  This would make the following queries much faster as they'd only need to filter results from the cached dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas's comments should be an answer to this question, in general form. A connection is being established and afterwards can be used. If anybody would like more technical information, they can read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) and even send feedback on the docs if more clarity is needed in any aspect.